# How to create Active FTP Connection through SSH Tunnel using Chilkat library

Tags: perl, chilkat

I'm trying to use an SSH Tunnel (using Chilkat library CKSshTunnel) to a remote server, that remote server is able to reach the destination FTP server. The FTP server requires an Active FTP connection, not passive. I do know the server will always use port 20 for data.

Is it possible to make an SSH tunnel, then use CKFTP2 with proxy settings to open an active FTP connection? I think the Active connection means the FTP client must open a receiving data port. Can it do that through the Chilkat SSH tunnel?

I'm able to make a tunnel connection, and open the FTP connection to the destination FTP server and see an initial greeting, but from there the connection times out.

"Failed to read FTP control channel reply."

```
#  Connect to an SSH server and establish the SSH tunnel:
my $tunnel = chilkat::CkSshTunnel->new();
$success = $tunnel->Connect('192.168.1.1',22);
    if ($success != 1) { print $tunnel->lastErrorText() . "\r\n"; exit;}
```

```
$ftp = chilkat::CkFtp2->new();
$ftp->put_Hostname("10.100.1.1");
$ftp->put_Username("anonymous");
$ftp->put_Passive(0);

$ftp->put_ActivePortRangeStart(20); # data port
$ftp->put_ActivePortRangeEnd(20);  # data port
$ftp->put_ForcePortIpAddress('192.168.1.1');

$ftp->put_SocksHostname('127.0.0.1'); # connect to local side of the tunnel
$ftp->put_SocksPort(1080);
$ftp->put_SocksUsername("secret");
$ftp->put_SocksPassword("secret");
$ftp->put_SocksVersion(5);
```

Comment: I have searched a little in the documentation of chilkat, but it seems that they don't provide any further functions for port forwarding in the ssh tunnel. So, instead of getting stuck in this kinds of errors, why don't you use some kind of wrapper like `Net::SSH::Tunnel`, there are variety that can solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You would use CkSshTunnel in dynamic port forwarding mode, so that the CkSshTunnel acts as a SOCKS5 proxy from the $ftp's point of view.  For example, see this:

https://www.example-code.com/perl/ftp_sshTunnel.asp

Comment: Thanks for this example Matt. This is actually what I was modeling it after.
Would this work with active FTP, where the client side must open up additonal data ports?

In testing, the connection itself worked, but the data port appeared to be the issue.